# Two questions about JsonProperty

Tags: java, json, jackson

Question 1:
Are

```
class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    @JsonCreator
    public Point(@JsonProperty("x") int x, @JsonProperty("y") int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

and

```
class Point {
    @JsonProperty("x")
    private int x;
    @JsonProperty("y")
    private int y;
    @JsonCreator
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

equivalent?

Question 2:
If I have a field that is not appeared in the parameters of the constructor, like:

```
class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int z;
    @JsonCreator
    public Point(@JsonProperty("x") int x, @JsonProperty("y") int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        z = 0;
    }
}
```

does Jackson still know about that field (z) and its value?

Comment: 1. No, likely they aren't equivalent. The first one is the way to go. The second case needs a default constructor, because it seems that Jackson doesn't try to guess field names from parameter names.

Comment: 2. With default settings Jackson simply ignores all private fields.

Answer (score 0):

In order to serialize/deserialize classes with private fields and no formal getters/setters, I had to do the following:

```
mapper.enable(MapperFeature.CAN_OVERRIDE_ACCESS_MODIFIERS);
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```

and also define a private default constructor for my classes, like this:

```
public class ElementDesc {
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  private ElementDesc() { this(null, null, false); }

  public ElementDesc(/* a regular constructor with parameters etc */) {
    ...
  }

  private final String field1;
  private final String field2;
  private final boolean field3;
}
```

in this case Jackson can successfully serialize/deserialize instances of the class w/o need to use its regular constructor and (accessor) methods (if any).